# Android Parcelable write / read String List null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, parcelable

I'm trying to read a List of Strings and I keep having the following error:

[image: img]

with the following Parcelable class:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ActivePolicies implements Parcelable {

    private List<String> activePolicies;

    public ActivePolicies(List<String> activePolicies) {
        this.activePolicies = activePolicies;
    }

    public List<String> getActivePolicies(){
        return activePolicies;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringList(activePolicies);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ActivePolicies> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ActivePolicies>() {
        @Override
        public ActivePolicies createFromParcel(Parcel in) {

            try {
                return new ActivePolicies(in.createStringArrayList());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public ActivePolicies[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ActivePolicies[size];
        }
    };

}
```

It keeps giving me the exception on `createFromParcel()`, but I can't figure out why.
It seems a simple parcelable, but when I'm debugging at `readStringList()` from the Parcel class, the list is null.
But when I evaluate the value in `createStringArrayList()` before it's returning, the list is there with the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create constructor that accept Parcel

```
public ActivePolicies(Parcel in) {
    in.readStringList(activePolicies);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`in.createStringArrayList()`? Why are you creating a new String list when you want to construct your object?

Use this method.

> `Parcel.readStringList(List<String> list)`
>
> Read into the given List items String objects that were written with
>   writeStringList(List) at the current dataPosition().

Recommended: implement a constructor that accepts a `Parcel`, then, optionally a `readFromParcel` method.

```
public class ActivePolicies implements Parcelable {

    private List<String> activePolicies;

    public ActivePolicies() {
        activePolicies = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public ActivePolicies(Parcel in) {
        this();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

   private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      in.readStringList(activePolicies);
   }
```

In the creator.

```
return new ActivePolicies(in);
```

Comment: You are right. I want to construct the object. Even though using what you said, it still not working unfortunately. I'm using exactly what you said and added a set method for the List. So I can give a value to it. But still with null...

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, but you do need `readStringList` at some point

Comment: One app is calling a remote method from another which returns ActivePolicies. This remote application has the list value and so I return new ActivePolicies(list). Even though, it's keep messing with null when readStringList is called.

Comment: Then it sounds like the list is already null when you did `dest.writeStringList(activePolicies);`

Comment: Actually, try the update

Comment: I guess maybe I can't define a interface method in AIDL without input as I'm doing: interface IReferenceMonitorService {
 ActivePolicies requestActivePolicies();
}

Comment: it's not null when writing...

Comment: AIDL or an interface isn't a problem. I think you need actually initialize the list.

Comment: That's why I had a constructor in first place... The list is initialized when writeToParcel is called and still not working.

Comment: And I need a setMethod for list. Look: http://imgur.com/LrHCPlZ

Comment: I need to define an AIDL method with a parcelable input.

Comment: I think I need, I can't edit last comment (or I don't know how). Gotta test that...

Comment: Your stacktrace in the image seems to hint that the list is null at `readStringList`. Have you done `activePolicies = new ArrayList<String>()`, or not?

Comment: Yes I did. http://imgur.com/a/2RqEg, On the right there is the remote application method implementation and below the remote caller.

Comment: You didn't call `this()` in the constructor that accepts the parcel

Comment: Still not working even with this().

Comment: It's initialized but doesn't have the value. http://imgur.com/a/HVOAT

Comment: At that line, no, it won't have any data yet. That method copies the strings from the parcel into the empty list

Comment: `readInt()` returns 0, so nothing is read